# Is it safe to use a powered hub while plugged in?

Tags: usb, hub

I have a USB hub which powers itself when plugged in to USB, but also has a DC pin jack for using the hub as a multi-port charger if you don't have USB available (or want to provide charging to a device without connecting it to your computer etc.)

Is it safe to plug it in to say, my laptop USB AND have its DC pin plugged in to its wall wart too?

Answer (score 3):

Yes. That is a powered USB hub:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub

A single USB port on your PC can provide only so much power. If you have alot of devices plugged into hub your single USB on PC may not be able to power all the devices so that's where the outlet power comes in. Yes it also keeps devices powered when hub disconnected from PC or PC off. See power section of this Wikipedia article:
https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hub

Comment: I have had a powered USB hub for 7 years and it has been attached to my desktop PC all that time, powered by AC all the time that the PC is powered. No harm to the PC.